Script Python para mandar correo en Gmail, se quedan en Bandeja de Enviados pero no se envían
Tengo un script que envía correos, algunos de ellos con exceles de 20KB, de forma automática después de la ejecución de otros scripts. Para hacer el envío utilizo la librería de smtplib y python 3.12
Lo que me sucede es que, sobre quedarse los correos en la Bandeja de Enviados, de forma arbitraria algunos de los correos no llegan nunca a los destinatarios.
He probado a vaciar el correo desde el que se envía, dejando tiempo entre envío de correo y correo, pero no se soluciona.
Comentar que los correos se envían de forma secuencial, los  que no salen siempre llevan un excel, pero si lanzo el script diversas ocasiones no siempre son los mismos los que se quedan sin salir.

Edita la pregunta y coloca el script, obviamente censurando el usuario y contraseña de autenticación y algún otro dato sensible.
